# Passing JSON data from PHP to ASP.NET

Tags: php, mysql, asp.net, sql-server, database

I am currently running two databases mysql and ms sql server 2008 on two remote hosts. An i want to transfer data from MySQL to MS SQL Server on regular basis like at mid-night.

Note: Host running MySQL can only run PHP, while other running SQL Server can only run ASP.Net.

I have tried using MS SQL driver v3.0 for PHP but it is not working for me cuase i can't change php.ini settings.

My question is, how can i use PHP or Asp.Net to tansfer data?

Can i do it like this:

- run php script on one server and fetch data from mysql
- convert it to json
- send it to aspx file on other server
- connect to Ms SQL Server through asp.net and save data

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: soap/rest/xml pretty much any standard web service setup will work fine for data transfer between either application.  You can do push from one to the other using curl or you can do pull requests eg running php script pushes data to aspx script or running aspx script requests data from am xml web service on php application. either is fine.

Comment: @Irfan Why is MySQL code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can i do it like this:

### Yeah you can very well do it !

*Step 1:*

Execute a PHP Script , Connect to your database , query the results .. Get them in an array

*Step 2:*

JSON encode it using **`json_encode()`** .

*Step 3:*

Post the JSON Encoded data, using **`cURL`** to your ASPX page.

*Step 4:*

The ASPX page decodes the JSON Encoded data and does the DB Operations.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should fetch data from your `MySQL` database and then convert it to json, then pass this `JSON` object to .Net `WebService`.

**NOTE:** - I think use from .Net WebService is more secure and useful for this action.